# sql query returning 0 rows

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

I have this sql query which runs fine and return 3 rows when run on sql developer but when I execute the same query in a jsp page, it executes properly but doesn't return any rows. There is no problem with database connection because all other queries work fine. 
Server - Tomcat 7 
database - Oracle 10g

query -

```
select slno from lbk_tab where log_date = to_date('18-06-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

jsp -

```
String dtol = "select slno from lbk_tab where log_date = to_date('18-06-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')";
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(dtol);
if (resultSet.next()) {
     out.print(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString(1)));
}
```

Table lbk_tab has columns slno and log_date.

How can I fix this?

Comment: log_date is date or timestamp ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry a typo fixed it

Comment: @Abihabi87 log_date is a date

Comment: @litelite, yes he already did ... read the question again

Comment: @user8226043: There is no difference but still try once with- `resultSet.getString("slno")`. Also put try-catch to see if you are getting any exception.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Did you insert it in SQL Developer? Did you commit it?

Comment: @KeyurPanchal Not working and I am not getting any exception

Comment: Please check what @APC has asked. It's quite possible that you have inserted data via SQL Developer but haven't committed it.

Comment: @APC auto-commit is enabled so that's not a problem

Comment: If you say so. The thing is, questions like this where the database is doing something weird almost always come down to some configuration or environmental issue the OP has over-looked. Instead of asking "I've done everything right, why isn't it working?" consider asking "It isn't working what have I done wrong (or forgotten to do)?"

Comment: @APC but how does it work for all other stuff not including dates?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't return any rows?  Did you step through the code with a debugger?  Where does `out` actually go?

Comment: @AndrewS yup, intellij idea. Number of valid rows returned = 0. out goes to the web page

Comment: Try ressultSet.getString("slno");

Answer (score 0):

Try these things :

1. Classfiles are being generated afresh ? Clear & re-build project /
           workspace.
2. Print the query and try to run printed query. Theoretically it looks the same from code, but just to be sure..
3. Check for query being fired at database also, may be java messes
   with date object or date format. Hence the actual date fired from jsp says something else while fired at mysql points at something else ?  debug / log / print query actually fired at mysql
           end.
4. More clarity is required here, "to_date" referenced in query is
           function ?  what are column types.

Comment: Tried 1, 2 and 3. to_date is a function to convert date to a specific format. log_date is of type date.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to use to_char()

```
select slno from lbk_tab where log_date = to_char(to_date('18-06-2017','DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

Comment: what it's return error or 0 row and what type of your log_date can you mention it please.

Comment: returns 0 rows. log_date is of type date

Comment: what did you define right database for slno in DriverManager? i think that is a problem.